# Is the Reactor object threadsafe?

Tags: java, concurrency, reactive-programming, reactor, project-reactor

Is the Reactor Event threadsafe? What I mean is: Can I access it from any thread for example to do a mass-notify operation or to register some event handlers? Or do I have to lock it somehow?

Comment: It depends on your notification process , but you should build your logic in the way that it will be thread safe. I would say in 99 percent of logic it will be thread safe.

Comment: No object is threadsafe unless so designed. What does the Javadoc of this one state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reaching into a thread at random and tinkering with its data is generally not a good idea. You'd want to write your reactor in such a way that it's listening for external messages. Depending on your performance needs, this could be as simple as external pause/resume messages where the reactor stops processing other inputs when it receives the pause message.